# How do you create a flow / sequence of actions in PHP/laravel? (Checkout payment system)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

1. Scenario

You're building a checkout payment system for your online store. Once someone adds an item to the cart, you ask for an email, then payment, then go to a thanks page.

2. What's the best way to create this sequence of actions?
3. What I am currently doing

I'm starting at a **/checkout/email/** route where I ask for an email. When I get one, redirect to **/checkout/payment/**, after successful payment redirect to **/checkout/thanks**.

I'm using some middlewares to check if the cart is empty, if we have an email already skip to payment, etc etc. Those sort of middlewares to check the status of where the user should be so whenever they come back they go where they should be.

Comment: If your code is working then what's the problem?

Comment: Its hard to debug whats going on with all these middleware checks. Surely there is a better way

Comment: debug what? what's the error you're getting?

Comment: for the futuree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).